# How to check the simultaneous positivity of two multivariable functions in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, inequalities

Given two functions of several real variables, say `f[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := x1 + 3 x2^2 - 5 x3 - 7 x4;` and `g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := 3 x1 - 6 x2 + 4 x3 - 2 x4;` I want to know whether these can be *simultaneously positive* i.e. `f[x1,x2,x3,x4]>0` `g[x1,x2,x3,x4]>0` for some choices of parameters `x1,x2,x3,x4`. Is there some way of checking this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use "FindInstance" like:

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := x1 + 3 x2^2 - 5 x3 - 7 x4;
 g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := 3 x1 - 6 x2 + 4 x3 - 2 x4;

sol=FindInstance[
 f[x1, x2, x3, x4] > 0 && f[x1, x2, x3, x4] > 0, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]

{{x1 -> 1, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0}}
```

With this:

```
{f[x1, x2, x3, x4], g[x1, x2, x3, x4]} /. sol[[1]]

{1, 3}
```

Comment: Please use `g[x]` while verifying.

Comment: @Syed Sorry, nobody is perfect.

Comment: You can find multiple instances, e.g., `sol = FindInstance[
  f[x1, x2, x3, x4] > 0 && g[x1, x2, x3, x4] > 0, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, 5]`

Answer (score 2):

```
$Version

"13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)"

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := x1 + 3 x2^2 - 5 x3 - 7 x4;
g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := 3 x1 - 6 x2 + 4 x3 - 2 x4;

cons = Reduce[
  f[x1, x2, x3, x4] > 0 && f[x1, x2, x3, x4] > 0, {x3, x4}, Reals]

(* x4 < 1/7 (x1 + 3 x2^2 - 5 x3) *)

Assuming[cons, 
 f[x1, x2, x3, x4] > 0 && f[x1, x2, x3, x4] > 0 // Simplify]

(* True *)
```